# Windows file permission issue on PHP unlink() call

Tags: php, windows

I'm building cross-platform utility that installs stuff from various sources, including git. At one point i need to wipe out git repository - created through the very same PHP application in same cmd session - and get permission error:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
  Failed to remove file "c:\users\ieuser\appdata\local\openserver\.cache\ama-team\vagranted\resource-sets\54b90db6\artifact\.git\objects\f5\e1818e5467665f1f597fb7e044b3f78eabd55e": unlink(c:\users\ieuser\appdata\local\openserver\.cache\ama-team\vagranted\resource-sets\54b90db6\artifact\.git\objects\f5\e1818e5467665f1f597fb7e044b3f78eabd55e): Permission denied.
```

The file is in place (and it is not a directory), it's not opened through fopen or anything like that,  php `getenv()` call returns the same IEUser that owns the file, icacls tells me that this user does have full control over specified file (F in output), and i can easily delete this file manually from the explorer. So on the top level it seems that everything is correct - what may be preventing me to from deletion of files from PHP script running under owner user?

Comment: Not sure what else is going on in your script, but I think you would get permission denied if the file was in use by another process even if you would otherwise have permission to delete it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i'm quite (though not 100%) sure there are no other processes using that file and that my scrip did not access it directly before deletion attempt (only through directory listing).

Comment: Does the user have write permission to the directory that file is in? I think you'd also need that to delete the file. (After that, I'm afraid I'm out of guesses.)

Comment: The file might be being briefly locked by search and/or anti-virus functionality.  Have you tried waiting a few seconds and then trying again?

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes, i did, problem persists. AFAIK there is no antivirus software, i'm running  my application inside official windows IE9 virtual machine image for developers, there's nothing but vagrant and openserver over the defaults.

Comment: @Don'tPanic parent directory seems to have necessary permissions (`IE9WIN7\IEUser:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)`). Is there any thing like linux lsof to find file readers (if there are any)?

Answer (score 2):

The answer turned out to be pretty simple. Windows (in fact, it's NTFS, i guess) has a read-only file attribute, which git seems to put for all it's internal files (blobs in commits). Recursively clearing that attribute allowed me to wipe out repository as i wanted to.